# Yosemite as ftp server

Tags: macos, ftp

I have many problems with my Mac OS X. The system is only reachable via SSH, but not with FTP and not with SMB.
So I tried to concentrate on FTP, seems easier to debug and may be it's one problem for both services.

First I enabled ftpd with:

```
sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

Then I try to ftp. But nothing. I got the standard error: Operation timed out.

After that I tried it again and made a tcpdump on the MBP. Looks fine for me:

```
tdmacpro:~ root# tcpdump port 21
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Packet Tap), capture size 65535 bytes
17:32:53.539323 IP 192.168.0.58.49191 > 192.168.0.2.ftp: Flags [S], seq    2091779555, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 3,nop,nop,TS val 271391148 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

So the packets are reaching the MBP, but it did not answer.

After that I created a new virtual machine on my MBP to be sure that no switch makes any problem. Then the ftp client was in my virt. machine. But same error.

After that I tried a ftp user@MBP_IP, again same error.

After that I disabled fptd with

```
sudo -s launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

and started the ftpd manually with

```
/usr/libexec/ftpd -d -D -l -U
```

again the same problem.

Then I used another terminal and made a:

```
ftp localhost
```

This works. So I think the ftpd is configured properly. But I also controlled the ftp.plist with a new installation.
The same content.

So is there anybody out there who has any further suggestions how to isolate the problem or how to solve it?

Comment: Is there anything related to the problem in `/var/log/system.log` (or other log files) at either the timestamp you try to start ftpd or you try to access the server?

Comment: No, I only found that the the ftpd is enabled or disabled. I do not see any log messages from connection establishments to ftp. But I think this is a kind of standard. In my virt. Test-System I also see only enabling or disabling, but no login messages when the ftp connection is established.

Comment: Any reason not to use SFTP? Just curious.

Comment: Yes, I need ftp to backup configurations from an appliance, this appliance do not support sftp

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that it listening on the correct network interface? If connecting to localhost:21 works, but connecting to your LAN IP does not, it's likely just a misconfiguration. You can confirm with something like this:

```
$ netstat -an | grep LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.21                *.*                    LISTEN
```

You want to see `*.21` or `0.0.0.0.21` or `192.168.0.x.21`.

If you see `::1.21` or `127.0.0.1.21` then it's only listening on the localhost interface and won't be reachable from other systems.

I couldn't reproduce your problem on my Yosemite system; when I ran `ftpd` with the arguments you provided, it correctly listened on all interfaces (`*.21`).